# Changing project layout in SBT 0.10.x

Tags: scala, migration, sbt

I feel like an idiot, but I am not able to change my project layout with SBT 0.10.x. In my sbt 0.7.x project I added the lines:

```
override def mainScalaSourcePath = "src" / "scala"
override def testScalaSourcePath = "test" / "scala"
override def mainResourcesPath = "resources"

override def mainJavaSourcePath = "src" / "java"
override def testJavaSourcePath = "test" / "java"
override def testResourcesPath = "test" / "resources"
```

What would be the equivalent in 0.10.x ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Minimally, you can configure the base source directory in the `Test` and `Compile` scopes, then configure the resource directory in the `Compile` scope. That setting will be correct in the `Test` scope because by default it is relative to the `sourceDirectory`. Similarly, the `scala-source` and `java-source` settings will be correct.

```
sourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src")

sourceDirectory in Test <<= baseDirectory(_ / "test")

resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "resources")
```

To see this in action:

```
> set sourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src")
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to default-fcf187 (in build file:/C:/temp/)

> set sourceDirectory in Test <<= baseDirectory(_ / "test")
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to default-fcf187 (in build file:/C:/temp/)

> set resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "resources")
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to default-fcf187 (in build file:/C:/temp/)

> show test:resource-directory
[info] C:\temp\test\resources
> show compile:resource-directory
[info] C:\temp\resources
> show test:scala-source
[info] C:\temp\test\scala
> show test:java-source
[info] C:\temp\test\java
> show compile:java-source
[info] C:\temp\src\java
> show test:java-source
[info] C:\temp\test\java
```

You can inspect the relationships between settings in the shell with `inspect`; or by browsing the [source of SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/v0.10.1/main/Defaults.scala#L111)