# How to add log4J properties file with sbt and onejar plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to build a one jar file with sbt on a scala/java project.
All the project is correctly built and packaged except the log4J configuration file.

I did not find how to include it in the classpath of the final jar.

I tried to add it to `unmanagedBase` in the `build.sbt` file without success.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to stick with log4j? If not, you would benefit from its improved successor, slf4j. There is also a Scala pimped wrapper called slf4s.

Comment: Yes. It is a mixed project with java and scala sources and the old java sources were programmed with log4j. In Scala we already use slf4j and logback

Comment: In that case, I suggest using slf4j for all new code and perhaps using the log4j-over-slf4j bridge for supporting the old code (http://slf4j.org/legacy.html).

Comment: OK Thank you I will have a look at that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should work if you place the file in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Thanks. I finally managed to setup log4J programmatically so I do not require the properties file. I do not have a standard directory structure so I could not test that.

Comment: In case you neeed it in the future, you can configure the resource folders quite easily, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081194/changing-project-layout-in-sbt-0-10-x